# Add custom functionality on WooCommerce complete button

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I've a situation to add some data to the database tables on order status completed button.
[image]

I can see the url in class-wc-admin-post-types.php

[image]

Can someone help me for any hook? Or how the admin-ajax.php works? I have to add status to some of mine custom database tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will fire a customer's order is set to completed..

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_task' );
function custom_task( $order_id ) {

    // Only continue if have $order_id
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get order
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Do your thing

}
```

Comment: I've asked for complete button inside admin dashboard.

Comment: sorry.. than try woocommerce_order_status_completed instead of woocommerce_thankyou